# Can a 16 year old US citizen get a temporary residence visa?

Tags: germany

To start off, I am 16 years old. My question is, as a US citizen, would it even be possible to move to Germany to be with my boyfriend and his family permanently? Is there even a visa for that? We have met in real life together before but I unfortunately had to come back to America. Please provide me insight with any information, I want to get out of my home life situation.

Answer (score 2):

The first, and extremely important question: **Do your legal guardians agree?**

My answer assumes that the guardians of both of you are supportive, that your boyfriend is the same age as you are, and that you are in an age-appropriate relationship. The boyfriend angle may provide a stumbling block for the reasons outlined by [Nicolas](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/can-a-16-year-old-us-citizen-get-a-temporary-residence-visa/24932#24932).

US citizens can enter Germany visa-free for 90 days and apply for a residence permit *after* arrival. (Very few nationalities get this preferential treatment. The system is biased towards those who are *presumed* not to be economic migrants.) But to cross the border, as a minor you need the permission of your legal guardians. (Both of them, if there is more than one.)

Generally speaking, it is possible for minor US citizen to spend a year or so in Germany, provided the legal guardians agree and provided there are responsible adults in Germany to take care of the minor. This is typically arranged through a student/pupil exchange program, but having such a formal program is not required. You would probably have to attend a German school, depending on your exact age on arrival and on your academic credentials from the US. Going to school would be a very good idea, even if you don't have to.

The second question: **Who pays?**

If the parents of your friend are willing to handle things like food, housing, and medical insurance, a *Verpflichtungserklärung* where they promise to cover all costs may be helpful in getting the residence permit. As a student, you would not get a work permit.

If you are 16 now, consider to time things for the 2023/2024 academic year. By the end of the year, you would be almost adult. Adding a second year in a German school would be unusual for a foreign student, but not unheard of.

Comment: (+1) Is there a third question around the OP’s ability to speak German?

Comment: @Traveller, I don't think there is a formal requirement for a student to speak the language. And total immersion in a family will help.

Comment: Fair point. Just my opinion - I think the OP ideally should have at least basic German language skills (A2, say) in order to be able to interact and communicate inside & (possibly more importantly) outside the family, and also in case an objective is university study idc. The proposed host family may speak fluent English of course, but if not it might well be very hard for a 16yo not to feel isolated and out of their depth.

Answer (score 1):

There is a family reunion visa for Germany, but you are not eligible as a minor because :

> **original marriage certificate**, and two (2) uncertified copies,
> when applying for a spouse reunion visa **or
> original birth certificate** of your German minor child, and two (2) uncertified copies, when applying for family reunion to join your German minor child or
> **proof of filing a notice of intended marriage with the appropriate Registrar’s Office**
> (“Anmeldung zur Eheschließung”) in Germany, and two (2) uncertified copies,
> when applying for a “fiancé(e)s visa” in order to marry a German national

From the [visa document checklist](https://www.germany.info/blob/2435504/449087fce85bf517fa1d77d735f19d27/family-reunion-with-a-german-spouse-child-data.pdf)

You can't get any of these as it is illegal to marry as a minor

> In 2017, Germany adopted the ‘Act to Combat Child Marriage’[1]. It is designed to protect young girls and women from being forced into arranged marriages against their will. This law sets the minimum age for marriage at 18 years, without exception. It also provides that marriages contracted abroad can be annulled by a judge if the partners had not reached the age of majority at the time of the marriage.

From the [EU Parliament](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-9-2020-005357_EN.html)

---

The other way is to go study there and then, once you get married, transition to get a family reunion residence permit

Comment: Can I study there even though I am 16?

Comment: @beelover420 It's likely that you can enroll into a High School there, but I have no idea about the specifics

Comment: @beelover420 You can study there as a minor, but you will need the signature of a parent or legal guardian on many forms and applications. You should also consider wider aspects eg how you’d manage if your relationship with your bf broke down

Comment: @Traveller how well does my german need to be? and we already told each other that no matter what happens we want to stay together because we’ve been through SO much already.

Comment: @beelover420 people change their minds, people break up, people manipulate and lie, no matter which one it is - you'll need to be able to be on your own if/when that happens. As a 16 y/o I doubt you can, and even if you can - I doubt you can show that to the immigration authorities in a satisfactory manner. In any case, until you're no longer minor, you'll need your parents/guardians to keep signing off on things - have you discussed this with them?

Comment: @beelover420 You may not want to hear this, but IMHO a responsible host family would not be encouraging you to even consider this, and if they did, they wouldn’t be leaving it to you to look for advice/info on the internet. They’d also be doing it in conjunction with your legal guardian(s).

Comment: @beelover420, the German term *Student/Studentin* is for university students, while school students are called *Schüler/Schülerin*. At age 16, you are extremely unlikely to qualify for university, but you can and probably must go to school. Your exchange family must register you with the municipal authorities, and official questions will be asked if your are not at school as an exchange student. There will be lots of paperwork, which will require the **permission and active support** of your parents.